# Why are some questions protected although they have (frankly) low scores and only low-scoring answers?

Tags: discussion

There's a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/420354/how-is-caballito-blanco-expressed-in-english) down at EL&U about the correct English word for a child (for example) allowed to play by relaxed rules when competing against adults (for example) with a natural advantage at this activity. (The question's author provides some Spanish words for this privileged weaker player.) This question is protected to prevent "thanks!", "me too!", or spam answers by new users. To answer it, you must have earned at least 10 reputation on this site (the association bonus does not count).

What's the purpose of this protection? I know -- to prevent "thanks!" etc. But when is protection advisable? It seems to me that I've usually encountered this after a series of very good answers. But at the moment, I think, there's only one answer, and it has a score of zero.

Comment: It’s usually applied after one or two *poor* answers which have to be downvoted and/or deleted. And if the they’re deleted, you won’t see them, which means you won’t see the motivation for protecting the question (until you have 10k rep). The reason you’re used to seeing questions protected only after a series of upvoted answers is because of a natural correlation. Sometimes an answer strikes a chord and becomes popular, and attracts many answers, good & bad, and it’s the bad ones, not the good ones, which prompt the protection. Again, the bad ones may be deleted & therefore not visible.

Comment: Sometimes, quite rarely, the protection is applied inappropriately and punitively, as a kind of resentful last-ditch “mini closure”. I saw one of these yesterday when a mod tried to close a Q for triggering one of his pet peeves, but ultimately couldn’t defend the closure on procedural grounds as there was nothing about the question which violated any rules, and so he was forced to re-open it. But immediately after re-opening it, he protected it, to at a minimize the # of people who could provide an answer to a question which offended his sensibilities.

Comment: Also see *[When is a member expected to protect a question?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6756/when-is-a-member-expected-to-protect-a-question)* and [the help center page](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions).

Comment: But such cases are the exception rather than the rule, and are easy for the community to manage, as a single 20k+ user can unprotect a question, and is entitled to do so for such politically motivated protections (and the original protector can’t raise much of a huff, because of a Q hasn’t attracted a couple or more poor-quality As, there really is no ground for such protections). I did that with the mod-closed Q yesterday and I’ve just done it with the Q you wake about here (because I can see there are no deleted As on that Q, low-quality or otherwise, so no justified need for protection).

Comment: @Dan Bron I don't follow. If a question is protected because of bad answers, (1) how is that different from closure, and (2) why does the message say that it was protected to prevent "thanks" or "me too" responses? Who would be saying thanks or "me too" after bad answers?

Comment: @Chaim Closure prevents anyone from answering. Protection prevents only people with < 10 rep earned on the site from answering. That is, if a user has 10 or more rep (which you can get from answering one question and getting a single upvote), he can answer protected questions. No one, with any amount of rep, can answe closed Qs. The idea being that *complete* newbies may not know the ropes and therefore post low-quality answers. Protection *protects* a question (positive connotation) from bad answers; closure *closes* a question (negative connotation) from ever being answered.

Comment: The most common type of poor-quality answers are answers posted by complete newbies posting “answers” like “Thanks, these other answers helped!” (not an answer) and “I’m having this problem too!” (also not an answer). They do this because they’re new to SE and used to message-board sites where a thread is more of a conversation and there is no requirement that each post after the first (the Q) must be an answer and *strictly* an answer. Protection makes sure that the only people who can answer are familiar enough with the site structure (eg have answered once and gotten 10 pts) to not err so.

Comment: The answers to the second "original" question are outdated, the statistics cited are totally superseded. It doesn't answer *this* question.

Comment: I don't see how those linked broader questions specifically answer _this_ question about protecting "tumbleweed-y" questions.

Comment: I'm totally lost.  I'm the author of the linked question -- but I found this meta question totally by accident.  Anyway, I don't see any protection on my question.  On top of all that -- I don't see any potential to cause noise in my question.  Please, could someone succinctly lay out the story so far for me?  Because I truly have no idea what the tempest in the teapot is really about.

Comment: @aparente001 I was also surprised and a bit puzzled (and somehow flattered) by the activity here. The answer to my question seems to be that protection is for questions that are attracting (or, some think, will attract) lots of bad responses from people with low ranks on the stack exchange. But I touched a nerve about the propriety of moderator's using protection and closure in idiosyncratic ways for subjective reasons. And I also agree that the protection seems to have disappeared from your question without a trace.

Answer (score 4):

Moderators regularly defensively protect questions that have the potential to cause more noise than signal on the site.

I protected this one because in my experience, guessing-game questions soliciting uncountably many random unsupported one-liner one-and-done answers that wind up having to be deleted just make more work for everyone. We don't need that around here.

The same goes for questions about controversial, inflammatory, or potentially offensive topics, as well as for those that hit the Hot Network Questions list.

The community is invited to please Protect those as a matter of course.

Comment: -1. Don’t do that. It’s an abuse of the tools (not an abuse of mod power, to be clear, just abuse of regular 20K+ user tools). We don’t proactively protect questions; that tool is intended to be retroactive and is usually applied to questions which have gotten *too much* attention, instead of *not enough*. And doing so simply shoots ourselves in the foot: it makes it *even harder* to attract new users with a real interest in English, which is the remedy ColleenV (also a mod on ELL) suggests for your “how to raise quality on ELL thread”. Protection isn’t mini-closure, don’t abuse it as if it is

Comment: @DanBron That may be your opinion, but do not pretend it is more than that.

Comment: It is not my opinion, it is the **stated objective** of *protection* (not *vilification*) of questions, as documented in the official SE FAQ and on our own site by another mod, accessible from the “possible duplicate” link on this meta-Q. As for *not imposing one’s opinions on the site*: physician, first heal thyself.

Comment: @DanBron This one is [meta-tag:status-bydesign] We use it here for the purposes we use it, including the ones I have just explained. [ELU is “special” as far as protection is concerned.](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3164/2085)

Comment: First: that Q is from twenty frickin *twelve*, over half a decade ago, and long superseded by changes in site culture and by the duplicate you yourself just closed this meta-Q as, and second the top-voted and accepted answer *corroborates* what I just said: protection is for *wuestions which have received *too much** attention, as in the HNQ (supercollider); the protection is *retroactive*. Come, these exculpatory contortions are not a good look on you.

Comment: @DanBron That changes nothing whatsoever. It continues to be the operative situation on our site, and the guidance for the site.

Comment: (A) that’s an excuse, rules are always evolving on ELU due to changing community and overriding meta-posts, and we consistently tell people that just because something was acceptable in 2012 doesn’t mean it applies today, and (B) even if it were true (it’s not) the cited guidance applies to *questions which have already received too much attention due to the multicollider* and doesn’t apply in advance of such attention.

Comment: The site's community certainly has evolved since 2012. However the multicollider still exists and questions that reach it still garner unwanted attention. If a mod spots a question that looks likely to hit the multicollider, it makes sense for them to preemptively protect it.

Comment: And hopefully, once the heat is gone, _somebody_ unprotects them... No? Nobody does.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен Why *likely* to hit the multicollider? Why are we trying to fix problems in advance of them being problems? Do close questions *just in case* the OP later decides to make them unclear? How do we justify the *actual* opportunity cost of locking questions and shutting out new users, which we desperately need, with the unrealized and phantom *possible* risks of getting a couple bad answers which would be instantly downvoted and later deleted? How can a mod tell whether a Q is *likely* to hit the HNQ? How can others discriminate these oracular visions from the mod’s personal biases?

Comment: @NVZ Pre-emptive protection is used for specific types of questions that have historically brought in the dregs. The type of question wouldn't change once the heat is gone. It will always be the kind of question to attract crap answers.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Then I want to see these kinds of heuristics backed up with *real data*, or we simply cannot condone the kind of discrimination we’re seeing, especially not when coming from the empowered. It’s a **really** bad look. And a really slippery slope. If you want this to be a rule, then let’s (a) let the community, not individual mods decide, or (b) let the mods collect data about *these particular kinds of questions*, without cherry picking, vs *all other kinds of questions*, without cherry picking. Show us a SEDE analysis that answers to these Q these get sig more downvotes than others.

Comment: Why is this an issue for you now? This is the way we have done things for years. We'll get that information for you although I'm surprised you haven't already done the analysis yourself.

Comment: @danbron That's a bit of an odd comparison. Nobody expects someone to come back and edit their question full stop, although it does happen. We have learnt through repeated exposure what questions are likely to hit the multicollider. I do admit we need to try harder at unprotecting. Also the comparison to locking is unfair, as protection is nothing like locking. Preemptive protection is not an epidemic, it happens occasionally when experienced moderators see a question that will draw unwanted attention. I doubt we lose users through protection, I find it more likely that we retain users.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен I didn’t mean locking, I meant protecting. Thinko. And I am still not buying it. I think these preemptive protections are specifically applied to Qs which a particular mod finds distasteful, with precisely zero evidence from the Q itself that it will hit the HNQ. It’s a punitive measure when the mod in question cannot justify closing a question and can’t convince the community en masse to close such questions. And I don’t see anyone rushing to protect actual bad questions which then actually hit the HNQ and receive actual bad answers.

Comment: And the argument that preemptive protection is not an epidemic falls flat when the issue it ostensibly seeks to forestall is also hardly epidemic, and when it does happen it’s easy to repair and such repairs are effectively instant in practice, and the protection is applied inconsistently to only the kinds of questions the particular mod disdains, and not others with all the same qualities save one, and the protection also happens to happen after the mod is browbeaten into re-opening a question he’d unilaterally and unjustifiably closed, and the protections are ever more frequent.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Because I’ve seen it increasing significantly recently, and I’ve seen it happen *precisely* when a mod begrudgingly re-opened a question he’d unilaterally closed on a pretext, a pretext which he never applies to questions which *actually* exhibit the issues described by the pretext, but lack one key characteristic which has no bearing on topicality or HNQ-probability. If you stop to reflect that you *know what that characteristic is* without my mentioning it once, and recognize it does not increase either the likelihood of HNQ or impinge topicality, you can see why I’m so worried.

Comment: I don't have any idea what you are talking about. Do you have a link to some pertinent discussion that I might have missed?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox I could help you more quickly if you'd point out the specific part of my comments you find confusing.  I am trying my best to make myself as clear as I can (hence the using-up of all my characters in every comment).  I can write an answer on this if it would help. Maybe to one of the dupes here?

Comment: I don't understand what you think his pretext or the mystery characteristic is.

Comment: The mystery characteristic is pejorative language and particularly SWRs.  He's written more than one meta-post on the topic.  He makes his feelings about them known very well and very often.  He closes these questions as quickly as he can, on the general pretext of "show us an example sentence" or "no guessing games". But dozens of others which have no example sentence and are guessing games he leaves up to the recognizance of the community. Which makes it feel like he thinks moderation is the community's job, except where he's got an axe to grind.

Comment: Above: s/particular SWRs/particularly pejorative SWRs/. (Also now [I remember I brought this up before, although more circumspectly](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10392/how-to-discuss-something-with-the-mod-team-privately). I've been worried about this for a while.)

Comment: Now, since I've created such a fuss, I will say this: in general I am very happy with the mod team and all its members, and was especially glad to see the uptick in more immediate moderation and closure of crappy questions after the last election. I think that was a direct result of this particular mod having a good influence. But I also see these closures applied in a very uneven manner, and I wish the mod would recuse himself from pejorative language questions or influence other mods on them, because he has a particular bias. I do not want to see personal biases implemented by diamonds.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly -- you feel that perjorative language questions are not more likely to hit the HNQ and generate low quality answers? I myself agree with being as hard on SWRs as possible, but our site is flooded with them. It's like trying to bail out the ocean.

Comment: I'm saying whether they are or not, it is the mod's stated position that he finds them distasteful and wants them banned, and he is implementing that while ignoring problematic questions of other types. He's happy to let the community moderate when his personal peeves aren't triggered, but leaps immediately when they are. He's **diamond-ing this particular pet peeve**. And I don't think "potential" HNQ Qs need preemptive protection at all. In general I think the problem preemption prevents are mere annoyances and almost always immediately rectified with DVs, deletes, and *reactive* protection.

Comment: Let me put it another way: a mod is using his powers to implement, to his best approximation without conspiculously flauting larger rules, a policy he asked the community to stand behind, which the community expressly turned down. My feeling is he does this on a variety of pretexts, but the underlying motivation is self-serving (to the extent this peeve is bothesome to him but not bothersome to the community).  I worry because one, it seems audacious to continue when this has been pointed out in more private and also more public and circumspect terms, but also a really worrisome slippery slope

Comment: When did that happen?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Numerous times that I've pointed out to the mod, and many more numerous times I haven't.  You may feel free to go through his closures and protections and count the proportion which are in some sense "asking for a word or words to smear someone else", but the pretext is "guessing games" or "no example sentences", and *also* look at (a) how quickly he responds to these after they're posted while he's active, and (b) how many similar SWRs within 15 minute-before-and-after window of the questions he immediately shut down which *also* don't have example sentences but he didn't touch.

Comment: I mean, where is the policy he suggested that the community rejected?

Comment: @KitZ.Fox It's here: ["Can anything be done about mean-spirited requests for terminology?"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4842/can-anything-be-done-about-mean-spirited-requests-for-terminology). That's the principle one, but I remember there was another similar one he posted that I can't find now. I ask that unless the mods are going to protect or close *all* questions with quality problems (the pretexts), none of them cherry pick ones to protect or close based on their own personal peeves.

Comment: I see. That helps clarify things. Thank you.

Comment: In particular I ask that (a) tchrist recuse himself from any questions on pejorative language, unless he casts the 5th closevote on such questions, as a normal non-mod would, (b) that other mods recuse themselves from acting on any such questions at his explicit request, and (c) not have an implicit policy of interfering with such questions based on their pejorativeness alone, nor pretexts which hide such a motivation.

Comment: Let me know if you find this dataset useful: http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/789548/views-on-protected-questions

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Thanks for composing that. I'll be able to consider it more deeply if you could supply me with an interpretation. Just to clarify what I'm looking for: a comparison of Qs asking for pejorative language, which were not protected, which later received several LQ answers, LQ being measured by community consensus (downvotes / delete votes), compared to *exactly the same thing* for questions which are non-pejorative. I'd also like to see a big picture of how often the problem occurs overall, to justify a special rule at odds with other site guidance and meta-posts.

Comment: It would be even better if this particular comparison could be done for this one mod's specific moderation decisions (proportion of Qs he closes or protects vs ones he doesn't) vs. when the community does it. And if the numbers aren't, well, really convincing, I'd suggest it is not worth even the perception that a diamond mod is using his powers to implement his own peeves.

Comment: What I gave you is a list of questions that were protected, sorted by the length of time until they were protected (the first time). The data contains the post score, the number of answers, the number of comments, the view count, and the tags. I don't have time to digest the data more than that right now, but I believe you can find your answers with it.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Ok, If possible, can you add two things for me? One, who protected it, and two, whether or not it is tagged [tag:pejorative-language] (which [tchrist created](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/177310/revisions)) or either of its 2 synonyms? Also when those changes are made, could you clone that query but make it for closed questions since tchrist got his ♦, rather than locked questions? I am sorry to ask you to do additional work, but I'm no good at SQL, and I'm sensing no one will take my case seriously until I prove it with numbers (though I know what the numbers will say)

Comment: I will see if I can do that after dinner. I can't parse the tags easily though.

Comment: @DanBron Preemptive protection is not punitive. It is to help keep a question from experiencing a burst of disruptive activity. I disagree with your perception of the situation.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен  No one can forecast which questions will see a burst of activity. Furthermore, whatever qualities tchrist believes a Q has that will cause such a burst, he only happens to protect those that *also* happen to be about pejorative language, and only the ones he can get away with unilaterally closing straight off. In his case, it is punitive, he is exercising editorial control of this site, no matter how you stick your fingers in your ears and sing la la la. This behavior is over the line. I am tired of it.

Comment: @DanBron You believe there is an issue with tchrist's judgement when it comes to closing/protecting pejorative language questions. Instead of digging up statistics, can we just agree that the perception of bias is just as much an issue as actual bias and work from there? Would it resolve your issue if tchrist simply agreed to get another mod's input before protecting that class of questions? We all have things that get under our skin that maybe we don't have the best perspective on. I regularly ask other ELL mods to handle certain issues that I know I could use a 2nd opinion on.

Comment: @ColleenV Absolutely agreed on both points. The perception, even if mistaken, of mod bias, is a problem in and of itself. And I did ask that tchrist recuse himself from interacting with pejorative questions. I think that’s the best approach here. The bigger picture to me is I would like everyone to avoid censoring questions simply because we don’t like the kind of answers they’re seeking.

Comment: Pre-emptive protection is not censorship. It is protecting the site from low-quality drive-by answers. If someone is prevented from answering by the threshold, then they have only to use their talents to get 10 points on a different question, and then come back and answer. It doesn't prevent them from answering; it merely places an "established members only" cordon around the question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach That is true if and only if the protection is applied to questions merely to prohibit low quality answers, and applied consistently to all questions likely to produce low quality answers, and not only he ones a particular mod finds in poor taste. I have seen tchrist insta-close a question for “no example sentences” and not so much as comment on the question asked immediately before or after which have “no example sentences”. A rule becomes a prejudice when it’s applied selectively to *things we don’t like*.

Comment: You seem to be confusing (or at least conflating) protection and closure. The two are not the same. And, any moderator can only do so much. I'm sure I've homed in in the past on the question which is most likely to be troublesome and/or easiest to deal with, simply because I can deal with that and don't have time to deal with the lesser problems. Is that bias or a good use of time in protecting the site?

Comment: @AndrewLeach I am not conflating anything. I am saying tchrist has a vendetta against pejorative questions, particularly pejorative SWRs, and targets hem specifically for their *purpose*, not based on their other merits, and then retroactively creates reasons to censor those by interpreting the site rules as strictly as possible for these Qs whole not touching others. He’ll unilaterally close when he can get away with it (which is not the usual SE model), but if he can’t get away with that, he protects the question as the best approximation or closure. I’m not conflating, he is. Deliberately.

Comment: Dan, I appreciate your good intentions. I know you are trying to defend ELU. You see bias in @tchrist's mod decisions on "pejorative" word requests, but as far as I can tell the other ELU mods do not agree. At this point I think you have exhausted that avenue of inquiry. If you do not intend to drop the matter, I encourage you to bring it up with an SE Community Manager through the [contact form](https://english.stackexchange.com/contact).

Comment: @DanBron I think it is unreasonable to expect that one moderator should have their power limited because there's a conflict with one community member. It's fine to identify an area where you think someone needs to be a little more careful, but you seem to me to be over-reacting which is making it difficult to come to a constructive resolution. The only thing a moderator can do unilaterally to truly censor content is to edit comments. Everything else is reversible either by the community or by the mod team  (even comment deletions can be undone).

Comment: @ColleenV Normal users can't vote to re-open a question unilaterally closed by a mod.  So no, the only case we can reverse a mod's decision is on protection, but that unfairly shifts the onus from the mod to the community the SE moderation model is *explicitly* designed to go the other way.  And there isn't a conflict with "one community member", it is demonstrable that one moderation is exercising editorial control to quell his personal peeve, which the community explicitly rejected in a meta-thread. And in general it's on the people in power to check their power use, not us to reprove them.

Comment: And I do not believe I'm over-reacting, I'm attempting to make my case clearly and explicitly, outline my concerns, respond to specific critiques of my position, and point to broader policy. That no one seems to appreciate anything I'm saying or say "you have a point there" or in general move towards any kind of resolution of except "no, user who is worried that an elected mod is exercising undue control and setting a very worrisome precedent, you are simply wrong. Please stop responding now." Suggest to me a path forward.

Comment: The next step is to bring it up with an SE Community Manager through the contact form.

Comment: A pattern of selective enforcement of the rules is problematic in any setting. That, I think, is the core issue that Dan Bron's extremely articulate series of comments attempts to focus on. If fifty cars are going 70 mph on a stretch of freeway posted with a 55-mph speed limit, and a highway patrol officer stops only the one car that happens to be an old Volvo station wagon—and does this repeatedly, disproportionately singling out old Volvo station wagons—then we have a problem of selective enforcement. If something similar is happening at EL&U, I agree with Dan Bron that it should stop. ...

Comment: ...Obviously, what makes selective enforcement possible in the first place is a flood of rule breaking that renders consistent and systematic enforcement of the rule in question impossible. But if that is the case, perhaps we need to revisit whether the rule itself is poorly drawn or unrealistically stringent or (in the worst case) a formally neutral but practically invidious standard designed to make ticketing old Volvo station wagons administratively convenient.

Comment: @SvenYargs You're saying abuses of bureaucratic power such as prejudicial enforcement should not be tolerated. As far as I have seen, everybody agrees with that. So moving on. I'd like to discuss barriers to consistent and systematic enforcement with you further, but I think we've wandered far enough from the original question in this comment thread. I'd like to either bring us together at ELU chat or create a chatroom for the purpose.

Comment: @MetaEd Let's create a chatroom. It's harder for me because I'm usually on mobile (though not right now), but I'll try my best.

Comment: [Chat room created](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72132/barriers-to-consistent-and-systematic-enforcement).