# I would like to report an abuse of mod power

Tags: support, moderators

I’m reporting @tchrist for the abuse of his mod power, for the following reasons:

- Deleting comments that were helpful but didn’t serve [his question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505698/how-did-to-wish-that-come-to-hate-the-present-tense-in-the-subordinate-clauses) well:

All the comments from different users above were deleted. I want to believe this was a simple “decluttering” but he/she did not move the comments to chat like they had previously done before. He said *“I did the move to chat, I don’t know what you’re talking about”* in the transcript but as you can see the above comments were never transferred (I was referring to the comments above and that is the reply they gave after I decided to bring it up to them). A link to view [[image 1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhF9U.png) is there.

- Deleting comments of an instance where I reported said moderator for rude behaviour and inappropriate comments and inferences about my “grammar”

Unfortunately I didn’t manage to screenshot this :(

- I mentioned in chat that I noticed that he deleted these messages and he replied in a rather repetitive-spam like manner and decided to look at all my chat history, answers, questions or comments to compile a list of “my mistakes”
- In the chat telling me to be consistent with BrE and AmE spellings but later saying “defense” and “offence” in the same sitting. I then proceeded to say “some people are hypocrites” (which was deleted) and I was unfairly banned on chat for 29 days - when said moderator was the one sending me spam like messages.

This does not seem to me the appropriate behaviour of a moderator.

I have linked the following transcript [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96438/discussion-on-question-by-tchrist-how-did-to-wish-that-come-to-hate-the-presen).

---

Edit:

It is important to note several things:

1. I did not say tchrist caused my ban but I had stated that said moderator was showing digressive actions towards me **and** I was unfairly banned for what **initially said** 29 days and was changed to 24 hours at around the time I posted this question. A link to [[image 2]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIwfB.png) is there. It has been questioned that this could be a bug but I have contacted SE and they will provide more information << I will leave this matter at that.
2. A finding:  It seems that a moderator can ban a user for any set amount of time. It doesn't show that there is an automatic 30 min suspension when a user is suspended, but at the discretion of a moderator. If you think a 29 day suspension is implausible, how about a 3250 year suspension ([A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271270#271270))?
3. I'm editing my answer for the sake of cleanness. The images of screenshots can still be found if needed as e.g. [image 1]
4. I'm also editing and putting the images in links since, people have seem to forgot that the comments (whether they were fairly deleted or not; we cannot know as we cannot read the mind of a moderator and whether those deletions were biased or not. For example, if they were decluttering why delete all of them and not keep the useful ones? Those comments in [image 1] are just part of the comments deleted) and **that was not the only act of regression**. In effect:

**What happens if a user violated any of the [*Be nice policies*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct) in regards to the reasons I'm reporting said moderator? They could potentially be suspended or banned. But if a moderator violated these actions, it seems there is no recourse for them.**

Comment: Just as a note, I believe that once a series of comments are moved to chat, it's no longer technically possible to move a *subsequent* series of comments to chat. That could explain why that *particular* event happened.

Comment: @JasonBassford: That is correct. Diamond mods can only "move comments to chat" once.

Comment: Just for the record, it's normal procedure for more recent comments to be subsequently deleted after the first series has been transferred to chat. Trust me when I say this has happened to everyone, and the usual response to  complaints is that comments are ephemeral and are not supposed to replace answers. So that's one, the other bit of information you *might* find reassuring is that mods can view deleted comments. Very rarely are things redacted (hard deleted, i.e. permanently) on Stack Exchange, unless requested personally and only under certain or special circumstances.

Comment: Related: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10392/55623

Comment: I don't understand. None of those comments seem worth keeping. They aren't asking for clarifications to the question. Which ones would you have kept? The first few are obviously chatty and the last is comparing something completely different since _told_ behaves normally and is fine with both past and present tenses. The whole point of the question is that _wish_ requires past tense. Could you edit your question and explain why you think any of those comments shouldn't have been deleted?

Comment: @terdon is the comments the only issue here..? It is the things said on chat too and the abusive comment made. Apparently it’s okay for moderators to get away with *rude or repetitive behaviour in a spam like manner*...

Comment: and the fact *a flagged comment was deleted isn’t a coincidence* to suit said moderator’s convenience.

Comment: It's one of the issues and the one you've spent most of your question on, and the only one for which you provide evidence that us non-ELU-mods can look at, so I assume it's one you consider important. Your other points are either things that only local mods can see or misunderstandings. For instance, you were not suspended from chat for 29 days, you were suspended for 24 _hours_. And that wasn't done by an ELU moderator anyway. As for the transcript, neither of you comes off particularly well there, I really wouldn't press it if I were you.

Comment: @terdon Thanks. I noticed too it changed from 29 days to 24 hours, I suspect another moderator changed it in light, or to be sympathetic with my question.

Comment: Also I tried lower level stuff to try to resolve my issue. I flagged for moderator attention on chat and they were denied, they didn’t deem it a “serious case”. I also tried @ a specific mod on ELU and it didn’t work, unfortunately.

Comment: You were never suspended from chat for 29 days. You were suspended automatically for 30 minutes by the system (something you said was flagged and those flags were validated by enough users with >10k reputation) and then a chat moderator (not someone from ELU) increased that suspension to 24h. But you were never chat-suspended for more than that.

Comment: Anyway, all I am saying is that since you seem to feel something was handled wrongly with respect to the comments you show, it would help your position if you were to explain exactly how it was handled wrongly. Because all I see in your screenshot is comments I also would have deleted or flagged for deletion. You obviously disagree, so it would be helpful if you could give a reason for your disagreement.

Comment: @terdon this is strange, I took a screenshot on my PC when this happened... it definitely said **29 days** [link](https://imgur.com/mDUDW3w). I explained how it was handled incorrectly in the post and in the previous comment when I remarked "I flagged for moderator attention for said moderator team and it was deemed as not serious".

Comment: Huh. That is indeed odd. That looks like a bug, actually, because the chat suspension record that I have access to as a chat mod shows only 30min (the automatic one) and 24h and no mention of 29 days. Anyway, none of these actions were taken by tchrist, so shouldn't count against him in your list of grievances.

Comment: @AJ Hi, I decided to put the link in my answer. Is it possible for moderators to edit their own moderation actions e.g. changing a ban that was 29 days before deleting this log and making a new ban for 24 hours?

Comment: @aesking no it isn't. It's possible for a user to edit a screenshot, but not for a mod to change the record. So while we can be 100% sure you were never suspended from chat for a period of days, we cannot be sure that there isn't a display bug somewhere causing you to see the wrong message. We also can't rule out that you uploaded a fake screenshot (although that seems very unlikely since it would be a ridiculous thing for anyone to do).

Comment: I rolled back your edit since i) what you were showing is either fake or wrong but in any case not relevant (you were suspended for a day, not a month) and ii) that suspension wasn't imposed by the mod you are complaining about so the entire thing isn't relevant to your post.

Comment: @terdon I am offended right now by the accusations. If someone looks deeply or with more powers the system definitely said **29 days**. << This issue is what I’m talking about mod-abuse power. Can a diamond moderator not see it?

Comment: There are no accusations here other than the ones you are bringing. I never accused you of anything! Ont he contrary, I said that your uploading a fake screenshot seems very unlikely since that would be a ridiculous thing to do. The likeliest scenario seems to be that there's a bug somewhere that shows you the wrong suspension length. But since that's just a mistake, it doesn't seem relevant to your post here.

Comment: @terdon if it is a bug why is it my fault? and what right did that give you to roll back my edit? what is relevant here can be decided by the community. **this is why I posted this in meta**. I'm sorry but did I upload a fake screenshot of the comments too? This is ridiculous.

Comment: I have every right, as does any other user with enough rep to edit. But sure, if you feel it's so relevant, leave it. I thought your issue here was with tchrist, so why clutter up your post with complaints about other mods? Especially non-ELU mods? And I never said anything was your fault! Where did you get that from? On the contrary, I keep saying it was a bug in the system. At this point, however, methinks the lady doth protest a bit too much...

Comment: @terdon might it not be possible that the OP was suspended for 29 days and then, good sense prevailed, and it was reduced to 24 hours? I think the screenshot is relevant and I think implying someone of photoshopping a screenshot is a very risky affair *"...what you were showing is either fake or wrong but in any case not relevant"* and *"We also can't rule out that you uploaded a fake screenshot"*

Comment: @Mari-LouA If it was, it would be visible in the logs we have access to, but since it's not, we can't rule out that possibility too.

Comment: ***Unfortunately, it is not technically practical for moderators to perform more than one migration from the comment thread to the chatroom. So further discussion here will simply be deleted***. – MetaEd♦ Dec 3 '18 at 23:56 - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474850/pregnant-as-a-taboo-word

Comment: @AJ you're a mod on a different site but not on EL&U. Does the fact of you being a mod mean you can see deleted content and users' histories  network-wide?

Comment: @Mari-LouA In chat, yes.

Comment: @Mari-LouA what AJ said. I can also see the logs of ***chat*** suspensions, so I know there was never a 30-day ban. We can see when a suspension's length was changed. So either there's a bug in the display system or the screenshot was faked. But as I have stated every time I bring up the latter possibility, I am assuming it wasn't fake since it would be such a ridiculous thing for someone to do. And it isn't relevant because I also know that the chat suspension was given out by an off-site mod, so has nothing to do with the OP's issues with tchrist.

Comment: @terdon  Would an off-site mod be someone like a community manager or any user who also happens to be a mod from any site?

Comment: Off-site mods is usually used to describe moderators from another SE site. Basically, all moderators from any and all SE sites are also moderators in chat. The chat system is SE-wide (with the exception of [so] and [meta.se] which have their own), so all mods are equal on chat. We can all see chat moderation events like suspensions etc. So yes, _off-site mod_ means a user who is a mod on another site, not a community manager. These folks: https://stackexchange.com/about/moderators?by=users

Comment: @terdon Reading the chat moderator guide, moderators have the power to purge (delete messages or history as if they never existed): "**Deleting a message is typically enough; purging the history should be used very sparingly. In particular, do not purge history to “redact” entire conversations; it is critical that other moderators be able to review what has happened when there’s a problem**." If a moderator can remove all messages and the version history of logs, what's to stop them purging individual history logs or messages?

Comment: @aesking Moderators cannot touch the moderation logs. What you read refers to chat _messages_ not the logs of moderation actions. We cannot affect those logs in any way. We simply cannot touch those.

Comment: Okay if a log for a "29 day suspension" was initiated and it is possible to change the length of ban, does the log show this history (29 days -> 24 hours) or does it just update latter: like when you edit comments or posts to revise them?

Comment: Aesking you should write a report to [contact](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/contact), EL&U users cannot do anything here to help you. Be prepared to wait a few weeks before receiving an official answer. Everyone needs to cool down.

Comment: @aesking every change is logged and documented. So if you were first suspended for 29 days and it was then changed to 24h, then that would have been visible in the logs. For what I hope is the last time though, if you really feel the chat suspension was wrong, then take it to [meta.se] or [contact](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) SE as Mari-Lou suggested. The chat suspension was not imposed by an ELU mod, so nobody here can give you any more info on it.

Comment: @Mari-LouA and terdon, thank you. I will do that. I have contacted SE before regarding this kind of thing on another 'forum' and it was dealt with appropriately. However, I just wanted to consult lower levels first instead of the "higher ups" as a form of respect. I will update you guys on what they say.

Comment: I seem to be missing a link to the original question where all of this originally happened. I literally cannot check who did what without knowing *where* they did it.

Comment: @RegDwigнt The question in question (that sounds odd) is  ["How did “to wish that” come to hate the present tense in the subordinate clauses it governs, and why is it alone in this?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/505698/how-did-to-wish-that-come-to-hate-the-present-tense-in-the-subordinate-clauses).

Comment: @RegDwigнt Now that we actually know what this was all about, whatever people have said in comments, it is still quite odd that a mod is modding their own question.

Comment: @Mitch I agree with that. I think it should be a conflict of interest for a moderator to be touching their own question, their own answer, or any of the answers to their own question in any way other than as a regular user.

Answer (score 8):

From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28869/389569) to the Meta post "[What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-their-privileges):

> *It's often best for you to try to work things out at as low a level as possible.* If you have a problem with one moderator, it's faster for you to reach any of the other elected "Diamond Moderators" on your site as they have the most experience with your specific site and may even have seen other actions you have taken that give context to the issue at hand. Sometimes you want to go above someone's head (or even straight to the top) with a complaint or request, but realize that the recipient will wonder why this person with a complaint couldn't resolve it with the team of moderators that were put in place to do just that.

Earlier in the answer, it says how to contact another moderator:

> Flag for moderator attention and request a second moderator to have a look.

What you flag would be something as closely related to the problem as possible—the question, the answer, or one of the (still existing) comments under one or the other.

There was some interesting information in the comments under that answer.

For instance:

> There is an (unwritten?) rule that, if you complain about a specific moderator, then that moderator will not handle a flag that is about them, and will leave it for other moderator(s) to look at.

And also:

> Related: [Can moderators handle flags cast on their own content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306740/195817)  — “But Moderators are bound by *broad* prohibitions against conflict of interest.  If a Moderator were to find themselves in the middle of an incident in which they find themselves a party, **we ask that they recuse themselves and find another Moderator to resolve the conflict.**”

---

Without going into details at this particular time, I recently had a similar experience with regard to an abusive comment directed at me by a moderator—which was then deleted, but not before I had flagged it as abusive.

Not knowing if my flag would survive the deletion of the comment or not, I raised a custom flag against a still-existing comment, and (in the space provided) mentioned the name of the particular moderator, hoping that it would be handled by somebody else—as indicated in the information provided above.

As it turned out, both my original flag and then subsequent custom flag were marked as "helpful." This tells me two things. First, that my original flag *did* survive its deletion. (That's good to know.) Second, and mainly because my custom flag wasn't processed until many hours later, that it was likely handled by a different moderator. Of course, it was good to know that I seem to have been warranted in raising my concern about the violation of the code of conduct.

---

In short, I suspect that this is the best way of bringing such things to the attention of other moderators—just raise a flag, and it *should* be looked at by somebody other than the person involved. So long as others are aware of it, they will deal with it in the background as they should. (So far, I've had no reason to lose faith in the underlying checks and balances that should be in place.)

It can be tricky when the person you have a problem with is a moderator, but I suspect that we should still handle things in the same way as we would if they weren't a moderator. Probably there is more so-called fear involved in this specific case—but I'm going to choose to think that it's mostly unwarranted so long as you handle *yourself* politely and professionally.

Comment: thanks Jason for the insightful and really helpful answer!

Comment: Just FYI, when a comment is deleted, any comment flag that wasn’t specifically declined is marked helpful.

Comment: @ColleenV Ah, this is good to know. So *that* flag probably received no attention, and I was right to raise a second one. (Simply to bring awareness to the issue in general.)

Comment: When in doubt, raise a flag. Sometimes it’s not apparent to us when a flag has been raised on something we’re currently looking at. It’s entirely possible that whoever left the comment read it over and thought that it was too harsh and deleted it right after you raised the flag. Enough “rude” flags on a user will raise an automated “you might want to take a look at this” flag, but it’s possible none of the other mods saw that one particular comment flag.

Comment: Since two comment flags can be enough for the comment to be deleted, it's entirely possible that no-one saw it at all.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yeah, especially since it was likely no-one up-voted it. Also, if it had certain trigger words, it could have been deleted immediately by a single flag. There’s a meta post [explaining the details of comment voting and flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/273494) for anyone who’s curious.